# How to resolve class name to fully qualified in Java?

Tags: java, classloader

Is there any way in Java to resolve simple class name (e.g. String) to fully qualified one (e.g. java.lang.String) or better yet to Class directly? The only way that comes to my mind is to parse file for imports and figure out from classpath jars. Sure there must be a better way.

Comment: This can't be done in general (for example, List or Date). is there some kind of context that limits the packages to search?

Comment: You're right, it's context dependent and also probably not possible at runtime. I am compiling so I have a context. I'm using javax.tools.JavaCompiler to compile file but still not sure how would this help.

Comment: If you can list the imports in source code you can attempt loading the class from each package, but since you're in the middle of the compiling process it could be that the class can't be found because it hasn't been compiled yet...

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this in a general way, since the same class name can be used in several packages, for example "Date" can be java.util.Date or java.sql.Date. Unless you can somehow limit the search area, this isn't even theoretically possible.

Also, one must wonder what use case would require you to get a Class from an unqualified class name.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Juvanis Well, maybe I should formulate it as an answer. "Not possible due to logic."

Comment: (OT) Duuude where have you been all these years?? Remember me? (jsalonen)

Comment: @Joni Hiya there! I just finally moved over here from the sun..err...oracle forums (they became totally unusable). I've seen a lot of familiar names here. Too bad I can't bring my reputation over ;)

Answer (score 0):

Java compiler determines fully qualified names class names by trying to find classes on the class path with different combination of simple class names in source file and package names in import statements. Compiled classes (.class) always get fully qualified names.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    String str;
    Date date;
...
```

compiles to Test.class

```
public class Test {
  Ljava/lang/String; str
  Ljava/util/Date; date
  ...
```